# Generic type autofac change type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

i work with autofac with generic type injection, I want to call a function in base DI with another generic type injection. how i do it? it's possible?

for example:

```
public class FooRepository : BaseRepository<Foo>
{
    public FooRepository(IUser user) : base(user)
    {
    }

     public override int Add(Foo entity)
    {
        var d =base.Add(entity)

        //how declare BaseRepository<Bar> 
        var c = ?????.Add(entity.Bar);

        return d;

    }
 }
```

Comment: What's the code on `Foo` class?

Comment: Int id , String name, BarFoo Bar

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat alike `typeof(BaseRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Bar))`may or may not work depending upon context, which you did not actually specify. Be aware that I provided a reflection-driven solution, certainly slower than a normal subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

i found simple solution

```
public class FooRepository : BaseRepository<Foo>
{
   IBaseRepository<Bar> _barep;

  public FooRepository(IUser user, IBaseRepository<Bar> barep) : base(user)
   {
    _barep=barep;
   }

 public override int Add(Foo entity)
{
    var d =base.Add(entity)

    //how declare BaseRepository<Bar> 
    var c = barep.Add(entity.Bar);

    return d;

}
```

}

thanks